# como buscar um elemento em uma lista que está dentro de outra lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

> tenho as seguinte lista composta por listas.

```
[['julian', '0', '5'], ['ana', '10', '4']]
```

> e preciso usar uma função que me diga a posição de um elemento qualquer dentro dessa lista, tentei usar:

```
elemento = lista.index('julian')

print (elemento)
```

> e espero retornar

```
>>>0,0
```

mas só funciona quando eu especifico em qual das listas dentro da lista principal procurar, como eu poderia fazer para ele procurar dentro de todas as listas e mostrar a posição?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Para uma solução mais concisa e pitônica, [veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210470/4816).**

---

Você pode iterar pela lista inteira, elemento por elemento, procurando pelo item que você quer - ao encontrar, salvamos o índice do elemento numa variável e retornamos ela em seguida.

Veja um exemplo:

```
lista = [['julian', '0', '5'], ['ana', '10', '4']]

# vamos criar uma função de 'busca'
def encontrar(elemento):
    pos_i = 0 # variável provisória de índice
    pos_j = 0 # idem

    for i in range (len(lista)): # procurar em todas as listas internas
        for j in range (i): # procurar em todos os elementos nessa lista
            if elemento in lista[i][j]: # se encontrarmos elemento ('ana')
                pos_i = i # guardamos o índice i
                pos_j = j # e o índice j
                break # saímos do loop interno
            break # e do externo
    return (pos_i, pos_j) # e retornamos os índices


r = encontrar('ana') # chamamos a função e salvamos em r
print(r) # imprime índices
print(lista[r[0]][r[1]]) # usa índices na lista como prova
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: resultado da execução do código]

*P.S. Esse código não servirá caso existir mais de um elemento com o mesmo valor/nome (ele sempre retornará o primeiro que encontrar)*

---

#### Edit:

Para procurar por mais de um item com o mesmo nome, podemos salvar o resultado numa nova lista, desta maneira:

```
lista = [['julian', '0', '5'], ['ana', '10', '4'], ['10', 'ana', '4']]

def encontrar(elemento):
    lista_pos = [] # vamos salvar nesta nova lista
    for i in range (len(lista)):
        for j in range (i):
            if elemento in lista[i][j]:
                lista_pos.append((i, j)) # aqui adicionamos cada índice na lista
    return lista_pos # removemos os breaks, pois precisamos procurar na lista inteira

r = encontrar('ana')
print(r)
# o próximo print só funciona buscando por 'ana', pois ele espera que
# o retorno seja pelo menos dois elementos
print(lista[r[0][0]][r[0][1]], lista[r[1][0]][r[1][1]])
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: resultado da execução do programa]

Comment: Para o caso do mesmo elemento existir múltiplas vezes, creio que um `yield` deva resolver

Comment: acho que entendi, então caso existisse mais de duas listas como no exemplo teria que aumentar os loops?

Comment: @JulianVitor Editei para pesquisar por mais de uma ocorrência da palavra. Precisamos apenas remover os `breaks`, pois o programa não pesquisava na lista inteira - além disso, precisamos salvar mais de um resultado, então eu adicionei uma nova lista - dê uma olhada.

Answer (score 8):

Não analisei as outras respostas a fundo, mas me espantei um pouco com a quantidade de código para uma tarefa simples. Então proponho aqui uma outra solução:

```
def search (lista, valor):
    return [(lista.index(x), x.index(valor)) for x in lista if valor in x]
```

O uso desta função, no caso, fica:

```
lista = [['julian', '0', '4'], ['ana', '10', '4']]

def search (lista, valor):
    return [(lista.index(x), x.index(valor)) for x in lista if valor in x]

print(search(lista, "julian")) # [(0, 0)]
print(search(lista, "ana"))    # [(1, 0)]
print(search(lista, "0"))      # [(0, 1)]
print(search(lista, "4"))      # [(0, 2), (1, 2)]
print(search(lista, "foo"))    # []
```

Explicando um pouco o código:

```
x in lista if valor in x
```

buscará qual é a sub-lista que se encontra o valor desejado, armazenando esta sub-lista em `x`. O valor retornado será `(lista.index(x), x.index(valor))`, onde o primeiro será o índice da sub-lista na lista e o segundo valor o índice do valor desejado dentro da sub-lista. Perceba que o valor retornado será uma lista com todas as ocorrências do valor. Por exemplo, o valor "4" está presente duas vezes na lista e, portanto, possui dois valores retornados.

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/vrGE3B) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/VastEarnestBrowser)</sup>

---

A solução acima falha quando uma sub-lista possui o mesmo valor várias vezes. Por exemplo, na entrada:

```
lista = [['julian', '0', '4', '4'], ['ana', '10', '4']]
```

Seria esperado que a saída para `search(lista, '4')` fosse os pares `(0, 2)`, `(0, 3)` e `(1, 2)`. pois a primeira sub-lista possui duas vezes o valor `'4'`, mas é, de fato, apenas `(0, 2)` e `(1, 2)`, pois ele para de buscar quando encontra o primeiro elemento. Para contornar isso, adaptei a solução para buscar todos os elementos:

```
def get_all_indexes(lista, valor):
    return (i for i, v in enumerate(lista) if v == valor)

def search(lista, valor):
    return (list(product([indice], get_all_indexes(sublista, valor))) 
        for indice, sublista in enumerate(lista) if valor in sublista)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/9vYu72) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TwinAngelicWorkplaces)</sup>

Assim, a saída de `search(lista, '4')` será:

```
[[(0, 2), (0, 3)], [(1, 2)]]
```

Assim como o esperado.

---

Ou ainda mais fácil que isso, uma maneira simples:

```
lista = [['julian', '0', '4', '4'], ['ana', '10', '4']]

def search(lista, valor):
    for i, sublista in enumerate(lista):
        yield from ((i, j) for j, item in enumerate(sublista) if item == valor)

print( list(search(lista, '4')) )  # [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2)]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Kztt2R) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SingleIncredibleAddress)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Esse código parece ser longo, mas ele só está assim por que tentei fazer algo com que você conseguisse entender:

```
lista = [['julian', '0', '5'], ['ana', '10', '4']]
print(lista)

procurar = input("Digite quem você procura: ")

for i in lista:
    local = lista.index(i) # Primeiro elemento
    for b in i:
        if b == procurar:
            local2 = lista[local].index(b) # Segundo elemento que está dentro do primeiro elemento, pouco confuso, mas é isso aí
            print("Quem você procura está na posição: lista[{}][{}]".format(local,local2))
            break

print("Quem você procura:",lista[local][local2])
```

**Saída:**

```
>>> [['julian', '0', '5'], ['ana', '10', '4']]
>>> Digite quem você procura: 4
>>> Quem você procura está na posição: lista[1][2]
>>> Quem você procura: 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Fiz um pouco diferente colocando dentro de uma função, para que fique algo mais genérico.

```
lista = [ ["julian", "0", "5"], ["ana", "10", "4"] ]

# Realiza a busca dentro da lista
def busca(valor):
    i, j = 0,0 # indides incialmente definidos como 0

    # percorrendo lista externa
    for sub in lista:
        #verificando se o valor buscado esta dentro de alguma lista interna
        if valor in sub:
            # atribuindo o indice do valor buscado a j
            j = sub.index(valor)
            break # sai do loop
        i +=1 # incrementa
    else:
        # caso o valor buscado nao seja encontrado
        return None 

    return i,j


result = busca("julian")
print(result)
```

Usando somente um for você pode percorrer as listas internas e daí vai verificando com o uso do **in** se o valor procurado está em alguma delas.

Caso esteja a variavel **j** receberá o índice desse valor e o loop é parado e então é retornada uma tupla contendo os valores de i e j.

Caso não encontre o for finalizará a busca em todas as listas e como não ocorreu o **break** cairá na condição **else** e então retornará **None** pois não foi encontrado o valor buscado.

Comment: +1, um dos únicos que funciona de fato.

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma maneira um pouco mais clean que você pode fazer, basicamente consiste em pesquisar dentro da lista todos os objetos que fazem parte da condição, para isto usamos o `filter` e o `lambda` após isto, com esta lista de objetos que são pertencentes a condição você pode pegar os índices através do `enumerate`

Segue abaixo o trecho de código responsável por isto:

```
#Conjunto de dados
data = [['julian', '0', '5'], ['ana', '10', '4']]
finder = 'julian'

#Faz o filtro da lista atraves da condição especificada
condition = filter(lambda x: x[0] == finder, data)
#Converte o filtro para uma lista comum
filters = list(condition)

result = []
#Percorre cada item da lista enumerando
for index, item in enumerate(data):
    if item in filters:
        result.append(index)
```

Agora dentro de `result` você tem todos os indices que correspondem a condição

Answer (score 0):

As respostas anteriores, pelo que percebi, funcionam bem para o exemplo dado.

Contudo, caso tenhamos uma entrada com um nesting maior, digamos `[[[1, 2], [[[3]]]]]`, nenhuma solução anteriormente apresentada dará a posição do elemento.

Para uma solução genérica, segue um exemplo de código que utiliza recursão para retornar uma tupla que corresponde à posição do elemento `valor` em `lista`, onde cada novo elemento da tupla corresponde a um nível maior de nesting.

```py
def busca(lista, valor):
    for el in lista:
        if valor == el:
            return (lista.index(el),)

        if isinstance(el, list):
            x = busca(el, valor)
            if x:
                return (lista.index(el),) + x

    return False
```

A função `busca` vai retornar a primeira ocorrência do elemento `valor` na lista `lista`. É possível que `valor` seja uma outra lista.

Exemplos de resultados:

```
lista = [[1, 2], [[[3]]]] | valor = 3
posição = (1, 0, 0, 0)

lista = [[1, 2], [[[3]]]] | valor = 1
posição = (0, 0)

lista = [1, 2, [1, 2]] | valor = 2
posição = (0,)

lista = [1, 2, [1, 2]] | valor = [1, 2]
posição = (2,)
```