# Filtrar um elemento especifico dentro de uma listra dentro de outra lista

Tags: python

Tenho um filtro para achar o index de uma listra dentro de outra lista(encontrei no grupo autor Anderson Carlos)

```
fila = [['vitor','5'], ['vitor', '4']]

def sdb(filadb,nome,elemento):

if not (filadb):
    return None
else:
    filadb_l = filadb[0]
    p = [(filadb_l.index(x), x.index(nome)) for x in filadb_l if nome in x] # linha 0 posicao 1
    if p == []:
        return None
    else:
        p_e = [(fila_pe.index(x), x.index(elemento)) for x in fila_pe if elemento in x] # linha 0 posicao 1
        p_linha = filadb_l[p[0][0]]
        posicao_e = fila_pe[p_e[0][0]][1]       
        p_elemento = p_linha[posicao_e]
        result = [p_linha]
        return p_elemento
```

retorno da função:

> > > [5]
> > >       Dessa forma eu tenho apenas um elemento.

Queria que me retornasse os 2 elementos.
retorno:

> > > ['5','4']

Comment: Possivelmente duplicada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210238/como-buscar-um-elemento-em-uma-lista-que-est%C3%A1-dentro-de-outra-lista

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa. Como sitei, eh outra pergunta. Ja vi esse poste.

Comment: Qual foi exatamente a sua tentativa? Coloca o código na pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss 
Ha 10 meses atrás uma pergunta foi lançada "Como buscar um elemento em uma lista que está dentro de outra lista".
Vc fez uma forma simples que me ajudou muito "[(lista.index(x), x.index(valor)) for x in lista if valor in x]". Desde já agradeço

Comment: Consegui resolver. Mais tarde posto a formula.

Comment: O que precisa fazer? Achar o índice de um valor ou achar todos os valores em um determinado índice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filaa = [(('vitor','5'), ('vitor', '4'))]
def sadb(filadb,nome):
    l = []
    if not (filadb):
        return None
    else:
        filadb_l = filadb[0]
        p = [(filadb_l.index(x), x.index(nome)) for x in filadb_l if nome in x] # linha 0 posicao 1
        if p == []:
            return None
        else:
            for item in p:
                lista = filadb[0][item[0]]
                n = lista[1]
                if not 'valvula' in l:
                    l.append(n)
            return l

print sadb(filaa, 'vitor')
```

> > > ['5', '4']

O código não está otimizado, mas funciona q eh uma beleza.