# Inserido em uma lista de listas em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de preencher uma lista em que cada posicao da mesmo fosse uma lista.

```
lista = [[], [], []]
```

tenho um input: 44 45 49 70 27 73 92 97 95

e gostaria de por na lista os numeros de forma q o indice seja mod de cada numero por 13.

Ex: 44%13 = 5
    27%13 = 1

```
lista = [[ ],[27,92],[ ],[ ],[95],[44,70],[45,97],[ ],[73],[ ],[49],[ ],[ ]]
          0     1     2   3    4     5       6     7    8   9   10   11  12
```

porem meu problema 'e inserir na lista interna, ja que toda vez q vou inserir,todas as listas internas ficam com o mesmo valor.
ex: `lista = [[1,2],[1,2]]`

OBS.: o input pode mudar logo a lista interna n tem um tamanho definido

Comment: Possível duplicata de [como buscar um elemento em uma lista que está dentro de outra lista?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210238/como-buscar-um-elemento-em-uma-lista-que-est%c3%a1-dentro-de-outra-lista)

Comment: Acho que seria bom você trabalhar com dicionários, ficará mais simples de trabalhar e até  visualizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, pelo problema relatado sobre as listas ficarem com os mesmos valores, você está inicializando da forma errada. Se você fizer:

```
>>> lista = [[]]*13
>>> print(lista)
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Você criará uma lista com 13 listas, mas todas serão a mesma referência. Se adicionar um número em uma delas:

```
>>> lista[0].append(1)
>>> print(lista)
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Todas receberão o valor.

[Listas de listas vazias (Python)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/298851/5878)

Você precisa fazer:

```
>>> lista = [[] for _ in range(13)]
```

Assim cada sub-lista será uma lista independente e quando adicionar um valor, ficará da forma que espera:

```
>>> lista[0].append(1)
>>> print(lista)
[[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Assim, basta adicionar os números nas respectivas posições:

```
for numero in numeros:
    lista[numero % 13].append(numero)
```

Ficando assim:

```
[[], [27, 92], [], [], [95], [44, 70], [45, 97], [], [73], [], [49], [], []]
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na sua criação de listas de listas.
Se você tivesse criado a lista de listas como colocou acima, com todas as listas internas criadas explicitamente, o problema não aconteceria - por que cada lista interna é um objeto separado:

```
In [1]: a = [[], []]

In [2]: a[0] is a[1]
Out[2]: False

In [3]: a[0].append("teste")

Out[4]: [['teste'], []]
```

Mas para encurtar o código, você deve ter usado a multplicação por inteiro, como forma de concatenar uma sequência com ela mesma. Nesse cenário, todas as entradas da lista interna são referências para a mesma lista externa:

```
In [6]: b = [[],] * 2

In [7]: b
Out[7]: [[], []]

In [8]: b[0] is b[1]
Out[8]: True

In [9]: b[0].append("teste")

In [10]: b
Out[10]: [['teste'], ['teste']]
```

No seu caso, como só quer mod % 13, a solução poderia ser simplesmente declarar as listas internas explicitamente, como você colocou no enunciado da pergunta. Mas, mesmo isso é um pouco inconveniente e pouco legível (alguém revisando o código teria que ficar contando as 13 repetiçoes) - e para números maiores é inviável.

O correto então é usar um `for` de forma que uma nova lista é criada em cada execução do laço.  No caso de Python temos a conveniente sintaxe das list-comprehensions que permite o `for` numa única expressão:

```
lista = [[] for i in range(13)]
```

Nesse caso, a parte da expressão `[]` que cria uma nova lista é executada uma vez para cada valor de i, e se torna um membro da lista externa - e o problema que você descreve não vai acontecer.

Answer (score 0):

**#INPUT**

```
listaNum = '44 45 49 70 27 73 92 97 95'.split(' ')
```

**#LISTA**

```
listaRes = []
for num in listaNum:
    listaRes.append([int(num) % 13, int(num)])
print(listaRes)
```

**#DICTIONARY**

```
dictRes = dict()
for num in listaNum:
    dictRes[int(num) % 13] = int(num)
print(dictRes)
```

Como já comentado, acredito que dicionários possa ser uma escolha interessante para um caso de chave/valor. A não ser que tenha outro motivo específico para usar a lista.

Comment: Não é exatamente esse o problema dele! Ele precisa adicionar `num` em uma lista no índice `int(num) % 13`, o que teria a lista que ele colocou na pergunta: `[[ ],[27,92],[ ],[ ],[95],[44,70],[45,97],[ ],[73],[ ],[49],[ ],[ ]]`